# AngularJS: orderBy not working

Tags: angularjs

All working but the orderBy not sorting items by order (value.points is a number)

```
<a class="item" ng-show="showResults" ng-repeat="(key, value) in event.tournaments | orderBy:'value.points'">
  <h3>{{key}} {{value.imitation}}</h3>
  <span class="badge badge-assertive">{{value.points}}</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy) , orderBy orders only arrays. The (key, value) sintax works on objects. Maybe transform your dictionary in an array will do the trick

Comment: if transforming a database is not an option?

Comment: you must not trasform the database, only the intermediate object providede to front-end, after the service returns.
Sorting object in javascript is not possible. Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069666/sorting-javascript-object-by-property-value

Comment: @n00b43677 you don't have to transform database, only the api delivering the data. Angular works best with arrays of objects rather than simple arrays. Data can always be mapped from one structure to another  in the client also

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be `orderBy:value.points` instead of `orderBy:'value.points'`?